# How to resolve 'Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.ts(2775)'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, tsc

I have the JavaScript code below, and I'm using the TypeScript Compiler (TSC) to provide type-checking as per the [Typescript Docs JSDoc Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html).

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const mocha = require('mocha');

mocha.describe('Array', () => {
    mocha.describe('#indexOf()', () => {
        mocha.it('should return -1 when the value is not present', 
        /** */
        () => {
            assert.strictEqual([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm seeing this error:

```
Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.ts(2775)
SomeFile.test.js(2, 7): 'assert' needs an explicit type annotation.
```

#### How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for not going deeper in the topic of the particular `assert` you use, it seems it is node native, which is different than [those supported by TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

But nevertheless, this can be a good hint:

```
// This is necessary to avoid the error: `Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.ts(2775)`
// `assertion.ts(16, 14): 'assert' needs an explicit type annotation.`
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36931#issuecomment-846131999
type Assert = (condition: unknown, message?: string) => asserts condition;
export const assert: Assert = (condition: unknown, msg?: string): asserts condition => {
    if (!condition) {
        throw new AssertionError(msg);
    }
};
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
assert(pathStr || pathParts, "Either `pathStr` or `pathParts` should be defined");
```

Answer (score 117):

### Cause

For anyone seeing this, if you have written your own assert function, keep in mind that TypeScript cannot use *arrowFunctions* for assertions.

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34523

### Fix

Change your assert function from an *arrowFunction* to *standard function*.

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that arrow functions can be written in a way that is incompatible with type assertions. So long as you provide explicit type annotation, arrow functions will work just fine ([example](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34523#issuecomment-700491122)).