# How do I tell TypeScript that my Type has changed/narrowed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a class that houses my API code for my application:

```js
export class Api {
  ...

  static requestData = async (
    abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
  ) => {
    // If previous request, cancel
    if (abortController.current) {
      abortController.current.abort();
    }
    // Set new controller for new request
    abortController.current = new AbortController();
    try {
      const response = await instance.get(
        "request/url/string",
        { signal: abortController.current.signal, },
      );
      if (response.success) {
        // Handle successful response
      } else {
        // Handle known error
      }
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      const signal = abortController.current.signal;
      if (abortController.current.signal.aborted) {
        // Handle aborted request
      } else {
        // Handle unknown error
      }
    }
  };
```

The Axios instance is defined earlier, using `axios.create`

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "base-url-path",
});
```

I want to refactor the code that aborts and creates the new `AbortController`

```js
    // If previous request, cancel
    if (abortController.current) {
      abortController.current.abort();
    }
    // Set new controller for new request
    abortController.current = new AbortController();
```

into its own function (to be reused elsewhere and reduce the amount of repeated code).

##### Attempt 1

I tried to move the above code to its own function inside the class:

```js
  public static abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController = (
    abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
  ) => {
    // If previous request, cancel
    if (abortController.current) {
      abortController.current.abort();
    }
    // Set new controller for new request
    abortController.current = new AbortController();
  };
```

So that I could do the following:

```js
  static requestData = async (
    abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
  ) => {
    this.abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController();
    try {
      const response = await instance.get(
        "request/url/string",
        { signal: abortController.current.signal, },
      );
      if (response.success) {
        // Handle successful response
      } else {
        // Handle known error
      }
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      const signal = abortController.current.signal;
      if (abortController.current.signal.aborted) {
        // Handle aborted request
      } else {
        // Handle unknown error
      }
    }
  };
```

But I get the error: `'abortController.current' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)`

##### Attempt 2

I also tried to use the `is` keyword
Example code that made me consider using `is`:

```js
export const notNullNorUndefined = <T = any>(
  value: T
): value is NonNullable<T> => value !== null && value !== undefined;
```

If a potentially `null`/`undefined` object is passed to this function, if the result is `true` the compiler accepts that the type of the object passed cannot be `null | undefined` anymore.
Attempt 2 code:

```js
public static abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController = (
  abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
): abortController is React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>  => {
  // If previous request, cancel
  if (abortController.current) {
    abortController.current.abort();
  }
  // Set new controller for new request
  abortController.current = new AbortController();
}
```

But this returns syntax errors: `A function whose declared type is neither 'undefined', 'void', nor 'any' must return a value.`

How do I tell TypeScript that my function (`abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController`) has mutated `abortController.current` so that its' type is no longer `AbortController | null` and only `AbortController`?

I would prefer not to assert the type where possible

Note, my package versions are:

- axios - 0.24.0
- react - 16.14.0

Comment: the return type should be `asserts abortController is React.MutableRefObject<AbortController>`

Comment: @Jerryh001 Agreed, and that's what I tried with "Attempt 2" (taking from the `notNullNorUndefined` function and trying to do the same with `abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController`), but I got syntax errors

Comment: @Jerryh001 Thank you! I used your suggestion and another answer to guide me to an acceptable answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jerryh001's hint and help from another answer (linked below), I was able to get to a solution:

```js
  public static abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController(
    abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
  ): asserts abortController is React.MutableRefObject<AbortController> {
    // If previous request, cancel
    if (abortController.current) {
      abortController.current.abort();
    }
    // Set new controller for new request
    abortController.current = new AbortController();
  }
```

Which meant that I could have the desired code:

```js
  static requestData = async (
    abortController: React.MutableRefObject<AbortController | null>
  ) => {
    this.abortPreviousAndSetUpNewController();
    try {
      const response = await instance.get(
        "request/url/string",
        { signal: abortController.current.signal, },
      );
      if (response.success) {
        // Handle successful response
      } else {
        // Handle known error
      }
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      const signal = abortController.current.signal;
      if (abortController.current.signal.aborted) {
        // Handle aborted request
      } else {
        // Handle unknown error
      }
    }
  };
```

##### Note:

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689922/15291770):

> keep in mind that TypeScript cannot use arrowFunctions for assertions.

The answer posts a link to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34523) which follows on to a [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53450).
Unfortunately, both of these threads are marked as "closed" so for the time-being you can't use arrow functions when using the `asserts` keyword.