# How to configure Typescript to infer discriminated unions when `is` and `never` is present?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I had a library in my project that I stopped using (deleted from `package.json`), and one of its peer dependencies was `fp-ts`, so I had to add `fp-ts` to my project. `fp-ts`  has an `Either` type which can be checked for left/right values:

```
export declare const isLeft: <E>(ma: Either<E, unknown>) => ma is Left<E>
```

If I put this in an `if`

```
if (E.isLeft(result)) {
    // ...
}
```

then in the `else` Typescript will correctly infer that my `Either` has a `right` value.

My problem is that ever since I moved the dependency to my project (instead of indirectly using it as a peer dependency) the following case doesn't work anymore, I get a compiler error:

```
const fail = (msg: string): never => {
    throw new GenericProgramError(msg);
};

if (E.isLeft(result)) {
    fail("Expected a successful result");
}
expect(result.right).toEqual(
    //        ^^^--- Property 'right' does not exist on type 'Left'
    // ...
);
```

The problem here is that if `result` is a `Left` then I `fail` which returns `never` (throws), so Typescript should be able to infer that in `expect` `result` can only have a `right` and not a `left`. And this was working before. What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't reference undeclared external code or libraries, unless the library is important enough for the question to be tagged with it (e.g., if you need fp-ts and/or jest for the question to make sense, then tag it with those; otherwise remove the references).  The goal is that others could copy and paste your code into their own IDEs and see what you're seeing, without being distracted by problems you're not having like missing definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that your `fail` assertion function should be a function statement and not a fat-arrow function.
(Thanks to david_p's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689922/81723)

So just change to `function fail(...): never` and it should work:

```js
function fail(msg: string): never {
    throw new GenericProgramError(msg);
}
```

Here's the full working example:

```js
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
declare function expect(value: any);

const result = E.right<string, boolean>(true);

function fail(msg: string): never {
  throw new Error(msg);
}

if (E.isLeft(result)) {
  fail("Expected a successful result");
}

expect(result.right).toEqual();
//     ^^^ ✅ result: E.Right<boolean>
```

---

**Why this works**

I stumbled onto the answer in a roundabout way.

I was trying to work this out by changing your code to an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

But I got the strange error: "Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.(2775)"

```js
const fail2 = (result: E.Either<any, any>): asserts result is E.Right<any> => {
    if (E.isLeft(result)) {
        throw new Error('Expected a successful result');
    }
};
    
fail2(result);
// Error: Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.(2775)
```

Searching for this error gave me [david_p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689922/81723) which explains that you can't use an arrow function as an assertion function (well, technically you can, but you need to explicitly define the type signature for the variable being assigned to. In practice it's easier to just use a function statement instead).

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I was thinking that this was due to some Typescript misconfiguration issue. Thanks for this!